# Outlook 2019 and actionable notifications in Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

I enabled email notification in Outlook 2019 in Windows 10. For some reason it only has a single button, "Ignore". The free version bundled with Windows 10 has two action buttons, how I can have the same result in the paid version?

I searched online and some results say that in Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016 you need to set app compatibility to Windows 7. Which is understandable because they were published before Windows 10.

But, for Outlook 2019, the app compatibility tab is missing because it targets the latest version of Windows from the start...

Maybe there is some setting that I missed, to enable the action buttons in the notifications?

Otherwise notifications just waste my time if i need to open the app to do everything

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test in Outlook 2019(version 2101), I could find three button in Outlook 2019 notification like below, so What's the specific version of your Outlook 2019?

[image]

Comment: I am on version 2101 too... I only have the dismiss button. Using gmail

Comment: Like this... https://imgur.com/V6NITGW

Comment: You are right, I have performed more tests about it and found: 1.For exchange account: we could see 3 button: delete, flag, dismiss 2.For gmail(imap) and another pop account, there's only a button:dismiss, so I think it may be more related to the account itself. Maybe you could try to add a exchange account for testing if it's possible.